# Is there any way to apply two "NOT Like" conditions in Civicrm API?

Tags: api, php

Hi I am using Civicrm api v3. I am trying NOT Like condition with single condition it is working. But i need to apply two conditions with string1 and string2.

```
    $contribution = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'get', [
        'sequential' => 1,
        // 'financial_type_id' => "Donation",
        'receive_date' => ['BETWEEN' => ["01-01-2021 00:00:00", "31-12-2021 23:59:59"]],
        'contact_id' => $contact_id,
        'contribution_status_id' => "Completed",
        'source' => ['NOT LIKE' => "%string1%"],
       'source' => ['NOT LIKE' => "%string2%"],
        'options' => ['limit' => 5000, 'sort' => "receive_date ASC"],
    ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do multiple not like statements using api4

[image]